# Google analytics events real time appeared, not in reports

Tags: java, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have hit events to google analytics using measurement protocol parameters from java.
worked fine more than 5 months.
but within a week event hits only appear in real time data, but not in reports.
JS api hits already works fine and no issue.

i didn't do any change. 
and no any events hits limit exceed notification or filters.

i have updated client id and parameter values. and tested more than one week.
no any improvement.

```
Properties p = new Properties();

p.setProperty("v", "1");
p.setProperty("tid", "UA-#########");
p.setProperty("cid", "######.####");
p.setProperty("t", "event");// hit type
p.setProperty("ec", "test category");// event category
p.setProperty("ea", "test action");// event action
p.setProperty("el", "test label");// event label
p.setProperty("ev", "1");// event value

sendEvent(p);//http post request
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Facing exactly the same one, have absolutely no idea how to solve this.

Comment: issue was the same cid reached maximum hit count. I used random 50 cids.